# Editing table row in PHP , but it is taking details of last row of the table

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

[image]I want to edit the contents of the row in the database. For that I have made a table from database with edit and delete button. Delete button is working fine with ajax. While clicking the edit button and moving to next page it is showing details of the last row in the table. I want to get details of current row that i have clicked the edit button.

My PHP code is

```
<form method="post" action="edit_team.php"> 
<?php
error_reporting(0);
//session_start();
include 'database-config.php';

$selectquery = "SELECT * FROM `register_team`" ;

$group_result = mysql_query($selectquery, $conn);

$a=0;

while ($container_id_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($group_result)) {
$a++;

echo "<tr class='gradeA odd' role='row'><td class='sorting_1'>" . $a . "</td><td>" . $container_id_record['team_name'] . "</td><td>" .$container_id_record['team_coach']. "</td><td>" . $container_id_record['team_manager'] .  "</td><td>" . $container_id_record['team_contact'] .  "</td><td>". $container_id_record['team_email']. "</td><td><button type='submit'><i class='fa fa-edit edit' title='". $container_id_record['team_name_coach']. "'></i></button></td><td><i class='fa fa-trash delete' title='". $container_id_record['team_name_coach']. "'></i></td></tr>";
  $team = $container_id_record['team_name_coach'];
}

?>
<input type="hidden" name="team_name_coach" id="team_name_coach" value="<?php echo $team;?>"/>
```

My edit_team.php is

```
$team_name_coach = $_POST['team_name_coach'];
```

While doing from ajax it is not showing the current value on the next page.

Comment: put `$a++` after ` $team = $container_id_record['team_name_coach'];`

Comment: Does it matters. It does not have any effect.

Comment: your are looping through each row in register_team table.. when the loop end the last row value will store in $team. thats why it is showing last row data,..

Comment: Ya I got that. While I am implementing with ajax with code it is showing current row details. But not passing it to next page.

Comment: can you show me your table which generated from the loop??

Comment: I have added image

Comment: is there only two rows??

Comment: Yes it can be more but at present 2 rows are there

Comment: can you post your js code?

Comment: @Prerana instead of making edit I would make it an anchor tag then make it look like `<a href="edit_team.php?id=$container_id_record[id]`; where id is the id of the team then on edit team I would use $_GET to get the id of the team and do my edits

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

```
  <form method="post" action="edit_team.php"> 
    <?php
    error_reporting(0);
    //session_start();
    include 'database-config.php';

    $selectquery = "SELECT * FROM `register_team`" ;

    $group_result = mysql_query($selectquery, $conn);

    $a=0;

    while ($container_id_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($group_result)) {


    echo "<tr class='gradeA odd' role='row'><td class='sorting_1'>" . $a . "</td><td>" . $container_id_record['team_name'] . "</td><td>" .$container_id_record['team_coach']. "</td><td>" . $container_id_record['team_manager'] .  "</td><td>" . $container_id_record['team_contact'] .  "</td><td>". $container_id_record['team_email']. "</td><td>
<a href = 'edit-team.php/'.$container_id_record['team_name_coach']><i class='fa fa-edit edit' ></i></a></td>
<td><i class='fa fa-trash delete' title='". $container_id_record['team_name_coach']. "'></i></td></tr>";




    }

    ?>
```

use $_GET instead of $_POST in edit-team.php page..
$team_name_coach = $_GET['team_name_coach'];

Comment: Still I am getting the details of the last row only.